# How to determine what block device (/dev/sd* or UUID) a particular file is on

Tags: linux, block-device

I need to generate a string for another application to locate my file. I need to know how to access this file dynamically.

```
customfile=/dev/sda1:/images/myfs.squashfs
```

Let's say I can `stat some/file/here.txt`. What command do I use to determine it's block device, and it's absolute path from that device?

Also, how do I then determine the absolute path to `here.txt` from the device?

Comment: You can get the device associated with the file with "df --output=source <pathtofile> | tail -1". If logical volumes are involved, more steps may be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find on which device your file is with [`df`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/df.1.html). Select the output columns with `--output` option. Note that `df` outputs the device which contains the filesystem. If you use *LVM*, *LUKS*, *mdraid* etc, the *source* column will contain the path of the logical device.

```
df --output=source $path |tail -1
```

From *target* column you can get the mount point of the device:

```
df --output=target $path |tail -1
```

To get path relative to the root of the mounted device, remove the mount point from the beginning of the path. Using shell [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02):

```
echo ${path#$(df $path --output=target |tail -1)}
```

Comment: Perfect.

Now, how about it's absolute path on that device?

Comment: Added an example using shell parameter expansion.

Comment: Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Running these 3 commands with /boot/vmlinuz-linux gives me ```/dev/sda1```, ```/boot```, and ```/vmlinuz-linux```. Perfect.

Comment: You should also post this answer over on the linked [duplicate] question as well, as this is far simpler and better answer.